# how to locate and click an element by div input_title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate and click an element by text. The reason is that the id and location of the element are dynamic but the text is always the same.

Here it is how look like as a HTML:

```
<div class="p-r" input-title="I want to identify by text here">
    <!---->
    <div class="skDeleteBtn skRequired">
        <input class="input radio--big ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" data-cname="radibutton" type="radio" id="z1jcfqy9">
        <label class="label label--radio-big" for="z1jcfqy9" style="color: inherit;">
            <span></span>I want to identify by text here
            <i class="d-ib va-m ml-3">
                <sk-tooltip><!---->
</sk-tooltip>
            </i>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to identify by text `I want to identify by text here`.

I want to mention that the location of the text where starts with `<span></span>` is a little bit weird. Specifically, i think that the text has whitespace and endline after the text, so I prefer to locate and click with `input-title="I want to identify by text here">`.
So far I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format('I want to identify by text here'))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'I want to identify by text here')]")
```

but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'I want to identify by text here')]`  and forget about the call to `format(...)`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have updated my attempts, I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to identify and click the input-title element? This should work, by text

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[input-title="I want to identify by text here"]').click()
```